# deploy my spring boot application in websphere liberty core i have error starting my app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websphere

When i deploy my spring boot application in websphere liberty core i have error starting my apps :

Com.ibm.ws.javaee.ddmodel.DDParser$ParserException: CWWKC2262E The server is unable to process the 4.0 version and the http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee namespace in META-INF/web-fragment.xml deployment descriptor on line 23

Please help

I try to deploy my spring boot application and i expect to launch it properly

Comment: Are you doing a WAR or JAR deployment of your springboot application?  Which version of Liberty are you using?  What features do you have specified in your server.xml file?  

Initial guess is your are using Servlet 4.0 deployment and the features that are started using Servlet 3.1.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.